# Javascript get list items

Tags: 2010, javascript

What I am trying to achieve is using javascript to check if a user has created an item for the post. So it would check if post ID = current post and created by = current user.

If it finds an item exists then it is to exit.

If item does not exists then I have another function I need to run to create the item.

The issue seems to be it's getting up to excutequeryasync then nothing is happening

Currently I have the following code.

```
function createListItem(decision, id, likes) {
var siteUrl = '/';
var countLikes = likes;

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('PostLikes');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where>"+
    "<And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='Integer'>  <UserID /> </Value></Eq>"+
    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='PostID' /><Value Type='Number'>" + id + "</Value></Eq>"+
    "</And></Where></Query></View>");
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(collListItem);
alert("1");

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
alert("2");
var listItemInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('PostID') + 
        '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Like');
}

alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: This is for a list I assume?

Comment: Yes it is for a list

Comment: Try to add some of your code to your question to clarify your problem.

Comment: Added the code im using

Comment: your CAML should look like this: `camlQuery.set_viewXml('<Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="Author" /><Value Type=”Integer”><UserID Type=”Integer”/></Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="PostID" /><Value Type="Number">' + id + '</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query>');`

Comment: Updated the CAML

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. Just added `<View></View>` to your query.

```
function createListItem(decision, id, likes) {
var siteUrl = '/';
var countLikes = likes;

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('PostLikes');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where>"+
    "<And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='Integer'>  <UserID /> </Value></Eq>"+
    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='PostID' /><Value Type='Number'>" + id + "</Value></Eq>"+
    "</And></Where></Query></View>");
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(collListItem);
alert("1");
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
alert("2");
var listItemInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('PostID') + 
        '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Like');
}

alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: It doesn't call the onQuerySucceeded, when it finds something which is what I want it to do. and call onQUeryFailed if it can't find an item

Comment: Are you sure you are trying with the code I posted because I've tested this and it works fine. If you're trying with your code, just know that the quotes are different in `Integer` in the CAML query.

Comment: I copied yours in exactly, it's getting up to alert("1");

Comment: Can you check in developer console (F12) what error you get?

Comment: Nothing apparently, I will add this script is run when a 'like' button is clicked

Comment: Weird... its working fine here. If this doesn't work for you then in your working code, copy the CAML query from my code and add it.

Comment: CreateListItem is undefined now

Comment: What change did you make? Just the CAML query?

Comment: Put " " around integer instead of ' '

Apologies for this, I'm having to self teach sharepoint

Comment: No. What I meant was Copy and replace the camlQuery.set_viewXml line fully.

Comment: That I've just done, still the same as I was getting before

Comment: Can you update your post with the code so that i have a better understanding?

Comment: I've updated the code in the original question

Comment: Can you remove the collListItem alert? You are alerting a null value.

Comment: Yep done that  :)

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Nope, gets to the first alert, then nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try using the currentContext by

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
```